# Joining two tables and only listing by specific value in shared field

Tags: join, where-clause

Trying to use INNER JOIN to combine two table in a class simulation. Once I've listed the fields I need to narrow the return to just items listed as category 3. Tried this

```
SELECT CategoryName, ProductID, ProductName, Unit, Price 
FROM Categories INNER JOIN Products 
ON Categories.CategoryID = Products.CategoryID
WHERE CategoryID='3'
```

but I get this

> "The specified field 'CategoryID' could refer to more than one table listed in the FROM clause of your SQL statement."

I understand the field is located in both and the query can't tell which table to pull CategoryID, but using

```
WHERE Categories.CategoryID='3'
```

doesn't work either. How do I structure the WHERE to point to the CategoryID  so that the query knows where to find it when both tables are being joined by the same field?

Comment: why doesn't it *work either* when you use `WHERE Categories.CategoryID='3' `